# Django Sessions Vs Browser Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms, local-storage

I am working on Issue where user has to go to some other page / url while filling a form. And after filling some data there in a form will come back to the page where he was previously filling the form. I can't combine the form because there are different forms which user has to filled. So i want to sustain the data user filled in first form before going to the other page for filling the data. For this i can use the localstorage of the browser or can use the django session. But in my forms there are several file fields which can have images, videos, audios and attachments upto 20 mb. So i don't know that will the browser support this much of data in localstorage or will django session store  it. 
**And I want to know if i serialize the form and store it to the local storage then will i be able to put that data back to the fields using the javascript. I don't want to use django form wizard which is not seems feasible because I am using Ajax for sending requests and Need to go to another page from half of the form.**

Guidance will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

The key problem you have here is the size of the data.Here are the limitations of it :

> Firefox can use IndexedDB, LocalStorage and SessionStorage.
>   LocalStorage and SessionStorage can use up to 10MB of storage but the
>   number is actually the sum of both. For IndexedDB, you can use up to
>   50MB on desktop, 5MB on mobile for free. However, the user can allow
>   the limit to be removed by granting permission.

[**What is the max size of localStorage values ?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)